# Cartesian product to direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

I have no idea, how to prove rigorously the corollary from the proposition. I know that i can use the isomorphism $\phi:x_1e_1+...+x_me_m \in \oplus_i^mvect(e_i)\to (x_1e_1,...,x_m e_m) \in \Pi_{i=1}^m$.

[image]

Comment: You should translate it into English so that others would know.  Anyway, the corollay is just a rephrasing of the proposition. Can you prove that $q_k$ and $\phi$ are **continuous**?

Comment: $q_k$ is trivially continuous: cause of the product topology on E we verify quickly that $p_i \circ q_k$ is constant or identity (depending on $i$) so continuous.  For $\phi$ we check the same way  $p_i \circ \phi$ is continuous.

Comment: Oups, i have a question! Wich topology can you put on $\oplus E_i$ ?

Comment: What do you mean? In corollary, $\oplus vect(e_i)$ is just $E$ there..

Comment: Ok there is a small misunderstanding. We are on the corollary so $E=\oplus vect(e_i)$ has a norm. Let's call $E_i=vect(e_i)$. Wich topology do you put on $E_i$ ? When you mean $q_k$ do you mean $q_k:E_k \to \Pi E_k$ ? By the way thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: $E_i=vect(e_i)$ is finite dimensional. So every norms on $E_i$ are equivalent. Hence, there is a unique normable topology on $E_i$. And yes, i mean $q_k$ as a canonical injection $E_k\rightarrow \prod_{k=1}^m E_k$.

Comment: We focused on the corollary so: 1) $E:=\oplus vect(E_i)$ has a topology induced by a norm. 2) I just understand that since $E_i$ is include in $E$ we can give him the induced topology (the one that make $i_k:(x_1e_1+...+x_me_m) \in E \to x_k \in E_k$ continuous by definition of induced topology). 3) Finally we can give $\Pi E_k$ the product topology. I am careful to not be confused between $i_k$ and $q_k:E_k \to \Pi E_k$. On the same idea i differentiate $p_k:\Pi E_k \to E_k$ and $\pi_k: \oplus E_k \to E_k$. In the hypothesis we have $E= \oplus E_k$!

Comment: Well, internal sum($\oplus$) and external sum ($\prod$) are set-theoretically different, but they have the same meaning. Anyway, it seems that you are a bit confused about normed space. I will write this with a detail as an answer.

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $q_k$'s are continous and $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. So that for any sequence $\{c_n\}$, $q_k(\sum_n c_n)= \sum_n q_k(c_n)$

Since $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $E$, $\{\phi(a_n)\}$ is a sequence in $\prod_{i=1}^m vect(e_i)$. Apply the proposition on this sequence.

Then, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(a_n)=\sum_{k=1}^m q_k ( \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_k(\phi(a_n)))= \sum_{k=1}^m q_k (\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k} e_k)= \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{n=1}^\infty q_k(a_{n,k} e_k)$.

Now apply $\phi^{-1}$ on both sides.

Then, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \phi^{-1}( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(a_n))= \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi^{-1}\circ q_k (a_{n,k} e_k)= \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k} e_k$.

============

It is much more than you have asked, but since it seems that you are confused in concepts, I will write this.

> **Definition**
>
> Let $(V,+,•)$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. Let $\tau$ be a topology on $V$ such that $+:V\times V\rightarrow V$ and $•:\mathbb{K}\times V$ are continuous. Then, we call $(V,+,•,\tau)$ a "topological vector space.

Let $||•||$ be a norm on a vector space $V$. Since $d(x,y):=||x-y||$ is a metric on $V$, we can give $V$ the metric topology. Let call this metric topology, "the topology induced by $||•||$ on $V$.

Now we define what normable space is:

> **Definition**
>
> Let $(V,\tau)$ be a topological vector space. If there exists a norm $||•||$ on $V$ that induces the topology $\tau$, then we call $(V,\tau)$ is normable.

Here are theorems you can easily check:

1. Every normed space is a topological vector space.
2. Finite product of normable spaces (equipped with product topology) is normable.

======

Now we focus on the question you asked:

You can give a norm on any finite dimensional vector space and since norms are equivalent on finite dimensional, when you consider finite dimensinal case, there is one and only one **normable topology** on that space.

Since $vect(e_i)$ is a subspace of $E$, let it be equipped with the subspace topology. This subspace topology is obviously normable, and since $vect(e_i)$ is finite-dimensional, this topology is the unique topology on $vect(e_i)$ that is normable.

Since $E$ and $vect(e_i)$'s are finite-dimensional, $q_k:vect(e_k)\rightarrow \prod vect(e_i)$ is continuous and $\phi: E \rightarrow \prod vect(e_i)$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I thank you!! $q_k$ and $\phi$ are continuous because linear on finite dimensional space, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. It can be proven from that. However, they are also continuous even for infinite product space. Since $p_k \circ q_k= id$ is continuous and $\phi$ is indeed an **isometry**.

Comment: $\phi$ is an isometry if we choose the adequate norm at the departure and at the end.

Comment: You are right and that is a troublesome IMO. If it is an infinite dimensional case (i.e. $E=\oplus_{i\in I} vect(e_i)$ (internal sum), the range is no more $\prod_{i\in I} vect(e_i)$, but it must be $\oplus_{i\in I} vect(e_i)$ (external sum) and we need to **define** a norm on this external sum to make $\phi$ an isometry.

Comment: I just found a note (Bourbaki) https://books.google.fr/books?id=kTFSfmsjDM0C&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=topology+on+a+direct+sum+bourbaki&source=bl&ots=KVWsSoCxlo&sig=4rlUBrdpnqBXSj7kYBNUBT_CXrk&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNn829zvDKAhULVRoKHUIYBScQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=topology%20on%20a%20direct%20sum%20bourbaki&f=false that say that $\phi $ is continuous but not all the time an homeomorphism.

Comment: No. That reference is not about your case. In your case, $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. That $\phi$ is a morphism between topological groups but in your case $\phi$ is a morphism between vector spaces. These are different obvioulsy.

Comment: Thanks! I just saw that you graduate recently,  I am impressed by your level!